# SELECT MAX of 3 date columns for each column and apply to each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I would like to select the max date for each column for TwoCheckDate, FourCheckDate, SixCheckDate and return that max date for each row in a query grouped by RecentStageId. Here is what I currently have in my query.

[image]

So for TwoCheckDate I would want **2021-05-04 00:00:00.000** for each row where RecentStageId is 2022, for FourCheckDate I would want **2021-05-05 00:00:00.000** for each row where RecentStageId is 2022 and for SixCheckDate I would want **2021-05-05 00:00:00.000** where RecentStageId is 2022, but null for the rows with different RecentStageIds. If another date existed for that RecentStageId in another row, then show that.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: `If another date existed for that RecentStageId in another row, then show that...` Not sure what you mean by that.  Rather than "describe" the expected results, it's best to *show* them tabular format, so we can clearly see the relationships between the sample and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MAX OVER` for the 3 datetime columns.

```
SELECT 
  t.RowNum, t.AssetID, t.RecentStageId, t.StageName
, TwoCheckDate  = MAX(t.TwoCheckDate)  OVER (PARTITION BY t.AssetID, t.RecentStageId) 
, FourCheckDate = MAX(t.FourCheckDate) OVER (PARTITION BY t.AssetID, t.RecentStageId) 
, SixCheckDate  = MAX(t.SixCheckDate)  OVER (PARTITION BY t.AssetID, t.RecentStageId) 
FROM YourTable t
ORDER BY t.RowNum;
```